# как можно сгладить углы дочерних объектов которые выступают за основу

Tags: html, css, frontend

```css
body{
 background:#2d4c61; 
}


.result{
  width:36%;
  border-radius:5px;
  background:#ffffff;
}
.harsi{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.harsi:hover{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background:#f0f2f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="result">


<div class="harsi">
dddd
</div>
<div class="harsi">
dddd
</div>


</div>
```

Надо чтоб при наведение на дочерние объекты они подсвечивались не выходя за основу, но при этом внутри (между собой) их нельзя скруглять

Comment: `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: А почему нельзя скруглять?

Comment: Это больше вопрос дизайна, так надо...внутри они должны быть прямыми...ответ дан, спасибо

Comment: Можно также первому элементу списка добавить border-top-left-radius и border-top-right-radius а последнему border-bottom-left-radius и border-bottom-right-radius.